# How to get 'Roll up summary field' in "Master Detail Relationship" on 'Detail page' using Formula?

Tags: formula, master-detail, roll-up-summary

Is it possible to get the 'Roll Up Summary field value' in the Master Detail Relationship on **Detail page** as well.

Basically to get a copy of 'Roll Up Summary value' in **Detail page** as well for a validation check. I would like to get via Point & Click using Formulas and not with any code. Is it possible? Is there any way?

I am getting a datatype error as below saying the fields datatype not valid for function when doing a simple syntax check
*Error: Formula result is data type (Object), incompatible with expected data type (true or false).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just created a formula field on a child object which takes value from Roll-up summary field of Parent. So yes it is possible.

My Rollup summary and formula fields are of following type:

**Rollup Summary Field**: Count *no of child records*

**Formula field**      : Number *type*

**Formula**: `Account.countopportunities__c`

I think there is some issue with formula you are creating. Sharing that could be helpful to solve your issue completely.

Comment: Can you share the formula used in the child object to display the roll up summary field from Parent object?

Comment: @Robertthomas It's just the name of rollup summery field like this: `Account.countopportunities__c`